# What is the URL for multiple paths in google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to enable the alternative routes between two points , i tried with this link

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chennai,%20Tamil%20Nadu,%20India&destination=Kodambakkam,%20Chennai,%20Tamil%20Nadu,%20India&sensor=false&alternatives=true
```

it is not giving any alternative routes.i'm working with android . can anyone give me the URL for alternative routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chennai&destination=Mumbai&alternatives=true
```

it is working me ! check with this